# Unable to deploy my ROR application to fly.io

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production

This is my first experience deploying a rails application to production. I want to deploy to Fly.io and have created credentials and initiated files fly.io configuration files for deployment. But when I deploy I get the following error:

```
 Starting init (commit: f447594)...
     Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 512 MiB (536866816 bytes)
     no label, UUID=af164c5a-e60d-4061-98ea-5d4af379bce2
     Preparing to run: `bin/rails fly:release` as root
     2023/01/01 07:53:05 listening on [fdaa:1:1737:a7b:80:5bf5:b65f:2]:22 (DNS: [fdaa::3]:53)
        Is the server running on host "::1" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
     could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:700:in `checkout_new_connection'
     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:341:in `checkout'
....
...
...
     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-
1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
     Tasks: TOP => fly:release => db:migrate
     (See full trace by running task with --trace)
     Starting clean up.
Error release command failed, deployment aborted
```

I followed the instructions given by Chris Oliver from GoRails & Deanin but that wasn't of any help as they can get it up & running with just a couple of commands. I believe my issue is in my config/database/yml file but I am able to figure out the specifics.

Any ideas on how should I debug this problem?

Comment: Database server (Postgres, I suppose) is not running on the port 5432. Not familiar with fly.io, but maybe they require additional setup to attach a Postgres db to your app instance

Comment: Actually, when I run fly launch and choose a pg database, It does not output the database credentials instead it asks me whether I want the Redis database, and even after that, I don't see any credentials shown. But it does create a DB app in my profile for my respective application and I don't know what to do with that!

Comment: I just checked and the `fly launch` command should ask you `? Would you like to set up a Postgresql database now?` and then it should output `The following secret was added to gold-dust-1234:
  DATABASE_URL=postgres://.....` and you should see `Set secret DATABASE_URL ` in the "Activity" section on the web dashboard.
If this does not happen, try updating the `flyctl` CLI and/or opening a ticket with Fly.io tech support.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this issue since the migration to v2. I solved this by checking 1 item on the fly.toml file:

1. App name is correct(line 6)

Once I corrected this, I encountered another issue. It appears the port number needed to be updated as well, on the same document.